# HTML::TableExtract doesn't work

Tags: html, perl, html-tableextract

The input html is [attached (my $file)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka3hc6x4feo5ubr/view-source_www.nasdaq.com_dividend-stocks_dividend-calendar.aspx_date%3D2017-Apr-19.html?dl=0), With the following script, I cannot extract the table I want. Any suggestions?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $file="view-source_www.nasdaq.com_dividend-stocks_dividend-calendar.aspx_date=2017-Apr-19.html";
open DATA,$file || die "cannot";

my $content;
{
    local $/ = undef; # slurp mode
    $content = <DATA>;
}
close DATA;

my $te;
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [qw(Announcement_Date)] );
$te-> parse($content);

# Examine all matching tables
foreach my $ts ($te->tables) {
  print "Table (", join(',', $ts->coords), "):\n";
  foreach my $row ($ts->rows) {
     print join(',', @$row), "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your file is actually an HTML page which contains the (escaped) source of another page. You probably want the original HTML, not the encoded version of it.

Comment: [HTML::TableExtract is beautiful](https://www.nu42.com/2012/04/htmltableextract-is-beautiful.html) ... "does not work" does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here.

Firstly, as [jcaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527940/jcaron) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43445887/htmltableextract-doesnt-work/43449598#comment73954261_43445887), you're not parsing the right thing. You seem to be parsing a "view source" page. You need to get the HTML directly. You can do that with [LWP::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple).

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.nasdaq.com/dividend-stocks/dividend-calendar.aspx?date=2017-Apr-19';

my $content = get $url;
```

Running your code now gives no errors but, unfortunately, it gives no output either. That's because you're defining the `headers` argument to the object constructor incorrectly. You use `qw(Announcement_Date)` but there is no table header with the value "Announcement_Date", so no matching table is found.

If you change the constructor call to this:

```
$te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => ['Announcement Date'] );
```

Then you get the expected output.